# Effective method on broadcasting the same notification to all the users in the database

Tags: php, mysql, backend, web-deployment, web-development-server

Hello guys i'm building a social network with HTML, CSS, plain JS, AJAX, MYSQLI, and PHP.

I been wondering what's the best method that you guys know personally from experience that is used to broadcast the same notification to all the users in the database.

Lets say I have a million users how would that work? I'm trying to find the most effective method on how to do this without making my database work really hard.

This is how my table look like.

[image: Example]

I'm not asking for anyone to code for me. All i'm asking is advice on a method that works best so I can get ideas on how to code this result effectively.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for some pub-sub service. You can find lots of free ones to start with. 
Take a look at https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ or https://aws.amazon.com/sns/
The idea is to publish the message from the server and have all the users subscribe to the channel/topic that the server is broadcasting the message to.

For a quick overview, you can refer to https://faye.jcoglan.com/

Comment: What if I want to not rely on others services or libraries. I basically want full control of what i'm doing. I was curious if you guys know any methods that you guys try before by your own experience not involving others peoples services or libraries. I'm wondering would it be over kill if I simply just create a script that sends the same notification data to all the users but that seems that will be a lot of copies of the same notification to all the users in the database. Or maybe that's how big social networks sites do that like facebook, twitter etc..

Comment: A quick implementation will need some refactoring to the database. I would create another table say `notifications` with columns 
```user_id, message_id, received(boolean), timestamp``` , where ```message_id``` will be a foreign key to the another table say `messages` which will store the messages to be broadcasted. Then make the client side periodically query this table and update with ```user_id and received``` upon successful message retrieval by the user. 
You can then continue to check the server for new messages with filter like `where user_id not {user_id}`.